# Initializing a control's member variable from device context

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, gdi

I'm writing a custom control derived from `CWnd`. I want to initialize a member variable  (e.g: a memory dc) of my custom control class using its device context. Which is the correct way to do it? I guess device context won't be ready in the constructor. So what is the next option. Is it safe using the dc the `OnCreate` event? I'm probably in search of something like `OnInitDialog`, but its a custom control, not a dialog.

**Update**: I added the custom control to the parent dialog via resource editor. So there is no chance for getting `WM_CREATE` event as it has already been created before subclassing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to sync the custom control to whatever is on screen?  That is atypical.

Comment: Have you tried overriding PreSubclassWindow ?

Comment: @wallyk no. I want to create a compatible memory dc for the custom control and keep it as member variable for drawing purposes.

Comment: @Ragesh, You are mixing two terms, Subclassing and Custom control. A custom control is something that you create from scratch; that is a new window class and a procedure associated with it. Subclassing is a technique to change the window procedure of an instance of a window class (a window in short) so that you can do some additional processing on the messages before it goes to the original procedure associated with the class. A custom control should receive a WM_CREATE message, no matter you created through resource editor or not. Now, are you talking about subclassing or custom control?

Comment: @Vishal A custom control is something that you derive from `CWnd` in my knowledge. It resembles writing from scratch. But when it gets created via resource editor, an `HWND` will be created using `CreateWindow` which will have its own window procedure until it gets `Attach`ed to my custom control class. Subclassing is used internally to switch the window procedure. That is why there is a function `PreSubClassWindow` available to override. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device context can be created in `OnCreate` (`WM_CREATE`), after you call the base class' OnCreate method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318297(v=vs.85).aspx

[From Programming Windows](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=giW4IIY_eMoC&pg=PT237&lpg=PT237&dq=wm_create%20device%20context&source=bl&ots=dYW_vlLxCb&sig=3MfWZyxI2LoGDmPsSosh8jiLgZg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6n_-T4_LDcftrAe97IjiBg&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=wm_create%20device%20context&f=false)